# ASP.NET Web API decimal validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

We have the following

```
public class Model
{
    [Required]
    public decimal Cost { get;set; }
}
```

When we receive an invalid value, such as "dasd" or whatever else, I return a BadRequest:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Model data) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

But in the response, the json looks like:

```
{
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "modelState": {
        "data.cost": ["Could not convert string to decimal: dasd. Path 'cost', line 1, position 181."],
    }
}
```

First of all, how can I get rid of the data. prefix?

Also, I would like to implement a custom validator, something like MustBeDecimal attribute that could allow me to return more userfriendly error
message.

Answer (score 3):

The Web API framework binds "dasd" to a decimal and it fails because it is not possible to convert "dasd" to decimal. Obviously, binding has to happen before validation. If you change decimal to string, binding will be okay and your regex validation will run and ModelState will be invalid but in this case also, the prefix that do you do not want to be present will be present.

The `Validate` method of `DefaultBodyModelValidator` has this `keyPrefix` parameter, which is used to create the prefix. Unfortunately, this method is not marked virtual for you to override. So, you will need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17114496) (see the first part).

Answer (score 1):

You can set an errormessage on the `RegularExpression` data-annotation attribute. Is there any reason you can't use this?

```
public class Model
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$",ErrorMessage = "You didn't enter a decimal!")]
    public decimal Cost { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: It would work for the MustBeDecimal attribute, but there is some validation occuring before that tries to convert the value to decimal, it throws an exception and this is what I receive as error. The regular expression validation is not even called.