# How can I remove the ModelState prefix on error messages in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, modelstate, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.0 API that will be consumed by my customers. One of the issues I am running into is that when I use ModelState for input validation of the request payload, the resultant error message that the consumer sees has a [objectPrefix].PropertyName in the response JSON. Our API documentation lists the Property name but not the object class and so the prefix is creating a problem when the consumer writes code that deserializes the JSON response in to their local object  model.

Is there any option I can set in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method for Service.AddMvc, or something similar, that will disable this prefix?

I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All(2.0.7) dependency in my API, .NET Core 2.0.4 and VS2016 v15.5.7 if that matters.

I am using Data Annotations from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations lib and decorating my creation DTO class properties like below;

```
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(14)]
    public string AccountNumber
    {
        get => _accountNumber;
        set => _accountNumber = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? value.Trim() : string.Empty;
    }
```

When the consumer doesn't provide an account number in the request payload, the error that returns looks like this;

```
{
    "[AccountDto].AccountNumber": [
        "The AccountNumber field is required."
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is elimintate the [AccountDto]. prefix so that the error JSON then looks like this;

```
{
    "AccountNumber": [
        "The AccountNumber field is required."
    ]
}
```

I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106151/how-to-remove-prefixes-from-modelstate-keys) post but it seems to reference the older ASP.NET.

Currently, I am having my client do a string replace on the json response but I really would like to have a better solution.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 5/16/18**

It seems that the issue with the prefix is related to my use of the Validate method in my *ForCreationDtos.

For example,

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        if (CompanyId == 0)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("A Company ID is required.", new[] { "CompanyId" });
        }

    }
```

However, I have found a work around by using a global ModelState handler and modifying it to parse out the prefix.

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates model state upon action execution
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">ActionExecutingContext object</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.IsValid) return;
        var errorList = context.ModelState.Where(ms => ms.Value.Errors.Any()).ToDictionary(
            kvp => kvp.Key.Replace("[0].", ""),
            kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorMessage) ? e.Exception.Message : e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
        );
        var globalErrorDto = new GlobalErrorDto { Errors = errorList };
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(globalErrorDto);
    }
}
```

This is a bit crude and assumes "[0]." as the prefix but that is the one that I get whenever I implement the Validate method in the DTO class. This seems to have solved my specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` v2.0.8, `Microsoft.NETCore.App` v2.0.7 and `Visual Studio` Community 2017 v15.7.1, and everything worked out like what you want.

#### Screenshot #1: No account number - 400

[image: No account number - 400]

#### Screenshot #2: Account number too long - 400

[image: Account number too long - 400]

#### Screenshot #3: Valid account number - 201

[image: Valid account number - 201]

I can't reproduce your issue. I even thought maybe I just created the model within the web project so I even created a separate class project to contain the DTOs. It still works out like what you want!

#### DTO

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DL.SO.ModelState.Dto.Users
{
    public class AccountModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(14)]
        [Display(Name = "account number")]
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
using DL.SO.ModelState.Dto.Users;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DL.SO.ModelState.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetById(string id)
        {
            // Just testing 
            return Ok(id);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(AccountModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            // Just testing so I pass in null
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), 
                 new { id = model.AccountNumber }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Startup

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace DL.SO.ModelState
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my DTOs, I am using Validate method (IValidatableObject interace) to check integer property values to make sure they are not zero. I believe that the prefix is coming from this method.

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if (CompanyId == 0)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("A Company ID is required.", new[] { "CompanyId" });
            }

        }

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer because it made me realize that the issue wasn't coming from ModelState in general but rather the Validate method, as described in my OP update.

Comment: Glad you figured that out! This is an off-topic thought: have you used FluentValidation library? In general I don't have validation logic in DTOs because they're meant to be Data Transfer Object. Instead, I have validations inside Domain Objects - represent your business models/roles. If you have time, you can take a look at that FluentValidation library. It's pretty neat!

Comment: @David_Liang I have FluentValidation on my ToDo list. I noticed that it still uses ModelState so I don't kn ow if it would make any difference on the prefix issue. However, as you stated, DTOs are supposed to be for transfer and so I plan to implement FV and move the validation out of the DTOs.  Thanks.